# Rscript uses C:/ for temp files even though TMP and TMPDIR set to another drive

Tags: r

My .Renviron file specifies

```
TMP = 'F:\temp' 
TMPDIR = 'F:\temp'
```

and in RStudio I get the following results:

```
Sys.getenv("TMP")
```

> [1] "F:\temp"

```
Sys.getenv("TMPDIR")
```

> [1] "F:\temp"

That part is the way it should be. I have 1 TB of free space on F:/ and less than 50 MB free on C:/.

However, when I run a script via Rscript as a scheduled task it always fails because it somehow reverts to trying to use the C:/ for temporary files and runs out of space.

How can I fix this?

In the current use case the major user of temp files is `fread.sas7bdat.parso` from the package `sas7bdat.parso`. I tried setting `tempfile=("F://temp")` in that function call, but it made no difference.

Comment: Is there a particular function that's creating temp files? What exactly are you doing that causes temp files to be created?

Comment: @MrFlick It's `fread`. Actually, in this case it's specifically `fread.sas7bdat.parso` but I did some experimenting and I believe it's more generally `fread`. I tried setting `tmpfile()` inline in the `fread.sas7bdat.parso` statements but it didn't help.

Answer (score 5):

Set them **system-wide** via System Properties' Environment Variables tab so they are set *before* R is started.  That is what Rstudio accomplished: it runs as a GUI/IDE *before* it launches the underlying R process.

Illustration:

```
edd@max:~$ TMP=/opt TEMPDIR=/src Rscript -e \   # line broken for display only
                       'print(Sys.getenv("TMP")); print(Sys.getenv("TEMPDIR"))'
[1] "/opt"
[1] "/src"
edd@max:~$
```

The demo is on Linux but the *concept* is the same.

Comment: It appears that this worked, thank you Mr. Eddelbuettel. It seems I set those variables some months ago and some SAS user decided to change them back. Please let me know if you have any recommendations for what I should do to them when I find out who they are. +1

Comment: Please do not edit my questions without my consent, or **at least mark them as edited by you**.  This now looks as if I wrote it, which I didn't so I would prefer to revert this. Thank you.

Comment: If you feel the need to add (cough) screenshots, feel free to add them to your question. Thank you.

Comment: But it's part of the answer and is more germane to the correct answer for Windows than a linux command line example, no?

Comment: Please allow me to decide what is part of my answer.